# new installation of windows 2008 R2 ... having permissions issues (everyone has access)

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, iis-7.5, anonymous

I can not limit access to the IUSR user nor the IIS_IUSRS group at all....not even a different user that I tried for anonymous access.

When I say IUSR below, I also mean I've tried adding the group IIS_IUSRS with the same result.

Things I've tried:
1) Removing the anonymous access user from the NTFS permissions (security tab) in windows explorer - user can still browse anything in the folder.
2) specifically denying IUSR read access (this works but I can't do this on all of my sites) - user can't browse anything in the folder
3) changing the anonymous user to a local account and removing their permissions on the folder - user can still browse anything in the folder
4) changing the Application Pool user identity to a local account that does not have permission to the folder - user can still browse anything in the folder
5) allowing IUSR read access to the folder but specifically denying write access - user can still upload files to the folder.
6) setting the site to use Windows Authentication and giving IUSR read permission to the folder - prompts for a UN/PW combo...that won't work
7) setting the site to use Windows Authentication AND anonymous access and removing IUSR from the security tab - user can still browse anything in the folder.

I'm pulling my hair out here!!!!  I've checked and tried everything I can think of, but nothing seems to allow me to restrict access to anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

Try a virus scanner. The symptoms you're describing could be FunLove related.