# is it ok to remove %machinename%\users from webroot windows 2008 R2 IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, iis-7.5, application-pools

I asked a question here: [new installation of windows 2008 R2 ... having permissions issues (everyone has access)](https://serverfault.com/questions/312630/new-installation-of-windows-2008-r2-having-permissions-issues-everyone-has-a)  last night about not being able to limit permissions to my web folders.  It turns out that it was because when I created a wwwroot folder on my d:\ drive (not the default c:\inetpub\wwwroot) it added my %machinename%\users group with "special" permissions (as well as read/execute).  I could never tell what the "special" permissions were (as far as reading, writing etc).  I therefore removed all access to my d:\inetpub\wwwroot for %machinename%\users and was able to limit access to IUSR and IIS_IUSRS the way I wanted.

I don't know enough about application pool identities etc to know if this may cause an issue down the road.  IE, I don't know if the application pool identity relies on the %machinename%\users group to do certain things.  Will removing permissions for that group force impersonation, will it cause other problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine.

As long as the accounts that actually need permissions to the content (IUSR and app pool identities) have them, you can remove the grant to the `Users` group.